# Mysql Entity Framework issue - Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

When I use this command:

```
$ dotnet ef database update
```

I get this error:

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

The table which cause this error is a built-in Microsoft table for user management:

```
CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserLogins` 
(
    `LoginProvider` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
    `ProviderKey` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
    `ProviderDisplayName` text NULL,
    `UserId` varchar(767) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`LoginProvider`, `ProviderKey`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I tried to add this to `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateurs>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateurs>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.RoleId).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.RoleId).HasMaxLength(200));
```

But it does not work anymore.

Thanks for your help

** EDIT **

I also tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(200));
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(200));
```

Comment: Did you regenerate the migration? Also make sure your code is after `base.OnModelCreating` call.

Comment: how can i regenerate the migration ? I have other database servers in production. do you think it will cause a problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I used official MySql provider `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` which is in pre-release state and has some troubles with migrations. Then I changed to `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and updated database without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Update MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore to the current version and check what connector is supported for your project at 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html#connector-net-entityframework-core-versions

also the example on the mysql website

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html